# How do I change a game's description in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

In the Roblox documentation for [basic place settings](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203314030-Basic-Place-Settings-Name-Description), it mentions how you can change the name and description of your game:

> Once on this page, you can change the Name and Description by editing the corresponding boxes.

However, I can only see a box to change the game's name and privacy:

[image: Missing a description section...]

How do I change the description of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/game-settings):

- Access game settings by clicking on the Game Settings button from the Home tab of Roblox Studio
  [image]
- Once open, you’ll see five tabs on the left side of the window: Basic Info, Permissions, Avatar, and Options, and World.
- The **Basic Info** tab contains options for general game settings, including the game description that players see.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But the documentation I linked is still wrong, so I don't see why I was downvoted for asking a question.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like the documentation you linked may be defunct - there's no date stamp on it, but it doesn't have the same UX layout as the docs I found from the main page. I'm not a roblox dev, so I made sure to check the date before posting my answer. I can sympathize with dealing with out of sync docs (I have similar issues with JMonkey). My best suggestion is to try to dig a bit further next time & describe the multiple things you've tried when asking to better demonstrate your research efforts.

Comment: i tried this, but it said "Data cannot be saved." Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2023 (v 0.580), the description can be changed from the File menu > Game Settings.  The Game Settings icon should also be visible on the far right of the Home ribbon.

[image: Game Settings]